PHP upload not working; file size appears to be the issue, but upload_max_filesize and post_max_size are set appropriately
NOTE: I'm a novice with PHP.
My PHP code uploads small files but silently fails with a test file of about 11M. So, I found a number of related questions, such as this one, and from that found /etc/php.ini, and updated post_max_size to zero and, since it doesn't appear to have a "don't set a limit", set upload_max_filesize to 128G - that ought to do it!
But no?!
I stopped Apache and restarted it, reloaded the client-side while testing, but it still doesn't work.
If you want to see the code - this is only the PHP portion... MAYBE some other aspect of this Apache configuration is holding back my application?
To wit:
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
        $errors = [];
        $path = 'uploads/';
        $extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'txt', 'mpeg'];
        
        $all_files = count($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']);
        
        for ($i = 0; $i < $all_files; $i++) {
            $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
            $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
            $file_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['files']['name'][$i])));            
            $file = $path . $file_name;                
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file);
        }

        if ($errors) print_r($errors);
    }
}

An additional issue is that I'm not getting any error output, but then maybe I'm not looking where the print_r code would send it? I'd like it to show up on the client-side's browser window "on the page."
MAJOR ISSUE
Using phpinfo() illustrates it's NOT honoring the changes I'm making?!
I proved the point: I'm editing the ONLY php.ini file there is on the system, this is confirmed from the phpinfo() data (below), and when I change it even slightly it is NOT honored!
YES, I've been restarting Apache every time.
As a case-in-point, I changed upload_max_filesize from 2M to merely 8M, but the data from phpinfo() doesn't change.
Note that I'm just doing a reload on a firefox browser to get the new data - could it be caching old data?!
Presuming not, this must be a platform issue?!
Platform data:
PHP Version 8.2.6
System  Linux server1 6.2.9-300.fc38.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Mar 30 22:32:58 UTC 2023 x86_64
Build Date  May 9 2023 06:25:31
Build System    Fedora release 38 (Thirty Eight)
Build Provider  Fedora Project
Compiler    gcc (GCC) 13.1.1 20230426 (Red Hat 13.1.1-1)
Architecture    x86_64
Server API  FPM/FastCGI
Virtual Directory Support   disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     /etc/php.d 

There's vastly more data available: if anyone can suggest what else I should post, I will!

Maybe there's an Apache setting limiting it.

You verified your php.ini is the one apache is executing? Do you get any errors in the logs?

@user3783243 Yes, according to "locate", it's the only one on the system. I did find an /etc/php.d directory and did some greps of it and didn't find anything with "max" in it. Logs: Nothing but specific references to the php script and "200", which I take to mean no errors. (These in the virtual host specific access / error logs - there was nothing in the server's main log.)

Usually I will check all the following php.ini parameters when I set up a new server: upload_max_filesize,
max_input_time,
max_execution_time,
post_max_size,
max_input_time,
memory_limit,
session.gc_maxlifetime

@KenLee Thanks, Ken, I'm looking into these things - and the new answer below - now. But your comment prompts a question: Do I have to cycle the apache server for changes in php.ini to take effect?

After changing the php.ini, remember to restart the httpd

phpinfo() is the best way to verify current PHP settings.

@Don'tPanic I tried that and CONFIRMED it's not reading the php.ini file. I updated the question...

(1) Is it true that the information you posted:  Loaded Configuration File /etc/php.ini and
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /etc/php.d  can be seen from <?php phpinfo(); ?> ? (2) If (1) is positive, then apart from php.ini, also check all ini inside the /etc/php.d (3) Consider re-starting the whole server if problem persists

Well crap: After hours of wasted time and FINALLY realizing that PHP wasn't accepting the changes I found this post that explains SOME ports of PHP are ... -ahem- DIFFERENT and you must, on my distribution, not only restart Apache but also do this:
systemctl restart php-fpm.service

That worked.
Note that I'm not inclined to close this question as a duplicate because if my version of the ask had been out there it would have saved me (and others) a LOT of time.
Thanks to everyone who tried and help me; I learned from you and appreciate it.

Do you have a request with the content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" header ?
post_max_size set to 0 does not work with some content-type headers.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size
Try to specify a value for post_max_size that is at least equal to upload_max_filesize.
For example:
post_max_size=128M
upload_max_filesize=128M

Note that memory_limit must also be at least equal to these 2 parameters.

I'm apparently too much of a novice to know how to address this - I don't know what's meant or how to address it: "a request with the content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" header " ... I've tried everything else and it isn't working so maybe that's the issue?

I changed post_max_size from 0 to 128G and it still doesn't work. I take it this would side-step the issue you stated about a value of 0 not working  with some content-type headers.
